# Add ## (Hashtags, Poundsigns, number signs, what have you) to a report header in SSRS

Tags: xslt, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a requirement that is difficult (apparently) to try and fill. I would like to add ## as a report header, OR as the first entry in the report. The report that is being generated is being utilized by a system parser that requires the ##. I know I can create an XSLT for it, and export as XML and transfer to CSV but that seems like way too much work for something as simple as adding a ##.

The problem is, we have approximately 30 of these reports to do like this. Creating XSLTs for all of them will be very time consuming. I would greatly appreciate some support from you gurus out there!

Thank you!

Comment: "*we have approximately 30 of these reports to do like this. Creating XSLTs for all of them will be very time consuming.*" Could you not write one generic XSLT that would handle all your reports? There is very little actual information in your question, but I believe XSLT is flexible enough. Anyway, if you don't want to use XSLT, why did you tag this so?

Comment: I suppose that I shouldn't have -- sorry Michael. The requirements differ for each XSLT, as does the data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible -- see below:

For CSV export, the report header is determined by the DataElementName property. However the property must be CLS-compliant identifiers, but “##” is not actually CLS-compliant. By entering these characters, you’ll get the error message: Property Value is not valid. So currently, it’s not supported to keep report header with special characters when exporting to CSV file.

You can refer to the article below:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255251.aspx
The relevant thread:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bc7bcae8-cce2-4626-8cb9-132a239a4ab8/ssrs-2008-column-issue-when-exporting-to-a-csv-file?forum=sqlreportingservices#f9bd33ae-6d92-4050-94d8-92c6e26e00cc